# Why won't this image fit to the screen size?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I posted a question yesterday trying to figure out why the sprite kit was distorting my image. I was given a great answer, however it was only semi-helpful for my problem.

I was told to name the image name@2x.png then to only call name in the code and that it would solve the problem. Unfortunately this didn't work.

This is what I was getting before trying that:

[image]

Code:

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"bgs.png"] size:CGSizeMake(568,320)];
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

[self addChild:background];
```

But after changing the images name to bgs@2x.png, and only writing bgs in the code, this is what I got:

[image]

Code:

```
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"bgs"]];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:background];
```

Which is closer to what I want but obviously still not right.

**Why won't it just fit to screen?**
What is going on that it either stretches the image too much or compresses the image too little?

IMAGE DIMENSIONS: 568 x 320 
GAME ORIENTATION: Landscape

Comment: is the image retina like if displaying 568 * 320 the image must be of 1136 * 640

Answer (score 2):

Your @2x image size must be 1136x640 to fill the whole screen. Just renaming it won't do the trick.

Comment: This is good to know but unfortunately it still doesn't solve my problem. When I use this image size it just makes it the same as the first image above ^